# JSON serializable error - Automatically update data to Google sheet

Tags: python, json, gspread

I would like to use python to connect data from Excel to Google Sheet.

But I got error "TypeError: Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable"

I guess the error happened in line with "wks.update_cells(cell_list)". May I know how to solve this kind of error? Thank you

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob
import datetime
import numpy as np
import time
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import json

def numberToLetters(q):
    q = q - 1
    result = ''
    while q >= 0:
        remain = q % 26
        result = chr(remain+65) + result;
        q = q//26 - 1
    return result


current_path = os.getcwd()
raw_df = pd.read_excel(glob.glob(os.path.join(current_path , 'Studio*'))[0],sheet_name = "Dashboard", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
df = raw_df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('startup_funding.json', scope)

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

wks = gc.open("Testing_Dashboard_Upload").sheet1

wks.clear()
columns = df.columns.values.tolist()
# selection of the range that will be updated
cell_list = wks.range('A1:'+numberToLetters(len(columns))+'1')


# modifying the values in the range
for cell in cell_list:
    val = columns[cell.col-1]
#    if type(val) is str:
#        val = val.decode('utf-8')
    cell.value = val

# update in batch
wks.update_cells(cell_list)


#4. handle content

# number of lines and columns
num_lines, num_columns = df.shape
# selection of the range that will be updated
cell_list = wks.range('A2:'+numberToLetters(num_columns)+str(num_lines+1))
# modifying the values in the range
for cell in cell_list:
    val = df.iloc[cell.row-2,cell.col-1]
    if isinstance(val, (np.float64, np.int64, np.bool_ )):
#        val = np.asscalar(val)
#        DeprecationWarning: np.asscalar(a) is deprecated since NumPy v1.16, use a.item() instead 
        val = val.item()
    cell.value = val

#5. update in batch

wks.update_cells(cell_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python json library wont serialize datetime object. You have to do it yourself. Find out which value in cell_list is datetime, and convert it to string using strftime method. From your code I think you are setting cell.value to a datetime object. If that so, you may change the line

```
    cell.value = val
```

to

```
if isinstance(val, datetime.datetime):
    val = val.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
cell.value = val
```

Comment: thank you. the script can run after the modification :)