# How to overcome "TypeError: Object of type 'datetime' is not JSON serializable" error?

Tags: python, json, excel, datetime, serialization

When I export data from excel to Google Spreadsheet, I am getting `TypeError: Object of type 'datetime' is not JSON serializable` error.

How can I solve this problem? Could you please help me?

Code:

```
xlApp = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:/Users/User/Desktop/ARCalc_05.2020 -.xlsx")
ar_excel = wb.Worksheets('AR').Range('A1').CurrentRegion()
data_excel = wb.Worksheets('Data').Range('A1').CurrentRegion()

aged_rec_gsheet = gc.open_by_url("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DIdwwdZ_Vk0OJQPohGBJvdVDBVlRMO9I-Sb6foNLmD8/edit#gid=1908610852")

aged_rec_gsheet.values_clear('Data!A:G')
aged_rec_gsheet.values_update(
'Data!A2', 
params={'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED', 
        'DateTimeRenderOption':'FORMATTED_STRING'}, 
body={'values': data_excel})
```

and the error I got:

```
body={'values': data_excel}
TypeError: Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable
```

I tried some ways to solve this problem (like creating a JSONEncoder class and function) but it couldn't work successfully.

Thanks

Comment: you tried changing it to string?

Comment: Yes, I tried it but it didn't work and I got another error kind

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61382337/json-serializable-error-automatically-update-data-to-google-sheet 

I tried to convert to string like in this link